# how to form 1 column from an existing column defining 3 levels using R?

Tags: r

My code

```
date$dmilk=ifelse(date$del<=100,paste("1",date$dmilk),
    (date$del>=100,paste("2",date$dmilk),
    (date$del>=200,paste("3"date$dmilk),
    (date$del>=300,paste("4",date$dmilk))
```

I would like to form the new `dmilk` column based on conditional constraints
Can someone help me?

---

```
del dmilk
21
320
362
288
81
66
267
235
229
425
383
361
197
260
106
238
74
102
148
197
329
428
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr)'s `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  del = c(
    21, 320, 362, 288, 81, 66, 267, 235, 229, 425, 383, 
    361, 197, 260, 106, 238, 74, 102, 148, 197, 329, 428
  )
)

df <- df %>% mutate(
  dmilk = case_when(
    del > 300 ~ 4,
    del > 200 ~ 3,
    del > 100 ~ 2,
    TRUE      ~ 1
  )
)

df

# A tibble: 22 x 2
     del dmilk
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1    21     1
 2   320     4
 3   362     4
 4   288     3
 5    81     1
 6    66     1
 7   267     3
 8   235     3
 9   229     3
10   425     4
# ... with 12 more rows
```

The evaluation of `case_when` conditionals is lazy. That is, the first valid entry is used, so I've switched the order. The final `TRUE` option is needed to complete unmatched entries.

Comment: i have 37.000 dels, how to concatenate? i used 22 just to explain, is it any different? sorry the question is very beginner

Comment: @BD'auria: There's no difference.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate your help ..
I was able to solve it in a simpler way .                                                             > caseina$dmilk[caseina$del <= 100]<- 1
> caseina$dmilk[caseina$del >= 100]<- 2
> caseina$dmilk[caseina$del >= 200]<- 3
> caseina$dmilk[caseina$del >= 300]<- 4
> caseina$dmilk[caseina$del >= 400]<- 5

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `findInterval` to get to the number you want and then create dmilk all at once.

You don't give us what was in dmilk so I just assumed it was the text "filler"

```
dat <- data.frame(del = c(21, 320, 362, 288, 81, 66, 267, 235, 229, 425, 383, 361, 197, 
260, 106, 238, 74, 102, 148, 197, 329, 428), dmilk = "filler")

val <- findInterval(dat$del, c(100, 200, 300))+1 #gives 0-3 so add 1 to get 1-4
dat$dmilk <- paste(val, dat$dmilk)
```

which gives

```
> dat
   del    dmilk
1   21 1 filler
2  320 4 filler
3  362 4 filler
4  288 3 filler
5   81 1 filler
6   66 1 filler
7  267 3 filler
8  235 3 filler
9  229 3 filler
10 425 4 filler
11 383 4 filler
12 361 4 filler
13 197 2 filler
14 260 3 filler
15 106 2 filler
16 238 3 filler
17  74 1 filler
18 102 2 filler
19 148 2 filler
20 197 2 filler
21 329 4 filler
22 428 4 filler
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the ifelse statement, you need to nest them. Also, conditions must be mutually exclusive in order to work fine. Finally, you need to add a default value when no condition has been met (I have used NA)

```
date$dmilk=ifelse(date$del<=100,paste("1",date$dmilk),
                  ifelse(date$del>=100 & date$del<200,paste("2",date$dmilk),
                         ifelse(date$del>=200 & date$del<300,paste("3",date$dmilk),
                                ifelse(date$del>=300,paste("4",date$dmilk), NA))))
```

Best!